# Background image being cut off (two images side-by-side)

Tags: html, css, css-float, background-image

I've been trying to position these images for hours. I keep running into problems and now my images are being cut off. I'm sure there are many things in my code that dont make much sense- i'm a newbie.

You can see it on codepen: ( as you can see, the left image is being pushed too far to the left outside of it's container)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPVXBK

And for some reason I'm getting a big space between images in my browser:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uts7xbmulpcrmqd/page1.png?dl=0

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header id="navbar">
    2222222222222222222222222222
    </header>
    <div id="all">

    <div id="sideNav">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"><a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Account<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Live Events <a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Football<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Baseball<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Soccer<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Basketball<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Hockey<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> MMA<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> eSports<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Tennis<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Cricket<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Golf<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Badminton<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Handball<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Rugby<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Snooker<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Table Tennis<a></li><hr>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#"> Volleyball<a></li><hr>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <section id="container">

    <section id="left">
    <div id="sec1">kdjskdkasd</div>
    </section>
    <section id="right">
    <div id="sec2">32939282</div>
    </section>
    <div id="sec3">dsjkjdsakjdkajads</div>

    </section>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00a087;
  }

/* Sidebar */

#sideNav{
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-top:42px;
  padding: 0;
  max-height:80em;
  background-color:#00a087;

}
.menu {
    line-height:50px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px dotted black;
    display:block;}

ul{ list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0.5em;}
a{text-decoration: none;}

a:hover{
    background-color:#fff;}

/* holds sidebar and content */
#all{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    max-height:128em;
    }

/* holds all center content */

#container{
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-right: 8em;
    margin-left: 8em;
    max-height: 64em;
    display:flex;
}

/* Left and Right columns*/

#right{
    border:1px dotted red;
    float: right;
    width: 51em;
}
#left{
    float: left;
  width: 51em;
}

/* sec1 is left container
   sec2 is right container */

#sec1{
    background: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq2v35frxg5cywm/football2.jpg?raw=1') no-repeat left fixed;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -moz-background-size: auto;
    -o-background-size: auto;
    background-size: auto;
    min-height: 62em;
      width:100%;
  float:left;
}

#sec2{
    background: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq2v35frxg5cywm/football2.jpg?raw=1') no-repeat right fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -moz-background-size: auto;
    -o-background-size: auto;
    background-size: auto;
    text-align:center;
      min-height:62em;
  float:right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that?:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGpjpL

Leave out the `left` and `right`in the `background` rules and set `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Hey, not like that. I don't plan on using this image two times, so I need the images to show 100%. I'd like the left image to be lined up to the left side of it's container (instead of being pushed too far to the left, where it ends up cutting off)

Comment: I'd like both images to be pushed to the center line, where both containers/wrappers meet. see:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uts7xbmulpcrmqd/page1.png?dl=0

Comment: I guess the problem is somehow related to the `display: flex` setting of the surrounding `#container`,  but I know to little about that flex stuff to give you good advice there.

Comment: another strange detail: around you `#container`you have a link tag - that makes no sense.  Also, in your menu there are lots of unused link tags - you really need to clean up your whole code before you go any further.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show the full size image and align right or left?
Then you should use:

```
background-size: contain;
background-position: left; //or right
```

Comment: Where do I add it? I tried using it in the right column, and left column. I also tried it in the sec1 and sec2 .

Answer (score 0):

Can you Photoshop a quick visual of what you are trying to achieve (using two different images) so a clearer answer can be given?